# what is wrong in this code? when i run it just shows 0 as the result

Tags: javascript

what is wrong in this code? when i run it just shows 0 as the result.i have checked with every known possible error.multiplication result is shown as zero.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculate</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>1st Number:<input type="text" id="firstNumber"></p>
<p>2nd Number:<input type="text" id="secondNumber"></p>
<button id="m">Multiply</button>
<button id="d">divide</button>
<p id="num"></p>

<script>
 var firstNumber,secondNumber;
 firstNumber=document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
 secondNumber=document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

 document.getElementById("m").onclick=function()
 {
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=firstNumber*secondNumber;
 }

 document.getElementById("d").onclick=function()
 {
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=firstNumber/secondNumber;
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are always empty strings, as you get them before someone clicks.

You have to get the values **when** someone clicks

```
document.getElementById("m").onclick = function() {
    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}

document.getElementById("d").onclick = function() {
    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = firstNumber / secondNumber;
}
```

You should preferably use `addEventListener` instead of inline javascript

Answer (score 1):

Make variables `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` pointers on your elements instead of retrieving values from outside the functions. That way you can access the value of the elements inside the functions.

```js
var firstNumber, secondNumber;
firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondNumber");

document.getElementById("m").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = firstNumber.value * secondNumber.value;
}

document.getElementById("d").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = firstNumber.value / secondNumber.value;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculate</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>1st Number:
    <input type="text" id="firstNumber">
  </p>
  <p>2nd Number:
    <input type="text" id="secondNumber">
  </p>
  <button id="m">Multiply</button>
  <button id="d">divide</button>
  <p id="num"></p>
</body>

</html>
```